# How to validate that a Java 8 Stream has two specific elements in it?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Let's say I have `List<Car>` and I want to search through that list to verify that I have both a Civic AND a Focus. If it's an OR it's very easy in that I can just apply an OR on the `.filter()`. Keep in mind that I can't do `filter().filter()` for this type of AND.

A working solution would be to do:

```
boolean hasCivic = reportElements.stream()
        .filter(car -> "Civic".equals(car.getModel()))
        .findFirst()
        .isPresent();

boolean hasFocus = reportElements.stream()
        .filter(car -> "Focus".equals(car.getModel()))
        .findFirst()
        .isPresent();

return hasCivic && hasFocus;
```

But then I'm basically processing the list twice. I can't apply an `&&` in the filter nor can I do `filter().filter()`.

Is there a way to process the stream once to find if the list contains both a Civic and a Focus car?

**IMPORTANT UPDATE:** The key problem with the solutions provided is that they all guarantee O(n) whereas my solution could be done after just two comparisons. If my list of cars is say 10 million cars then there would be a very significant performance cost. My solution however doesn't feel right, but maybe it is the best solution performance wise...

Comment: There isn't going to be another short-circuiting solution; if you want one you'll have to stick with your current approach.  Though: instead of `.filter(...).findFirst().isPresent()`, you should just write `.anyMatch(...)`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Good point about anyMatch(). I went the longer route because I was trying all kinds of additional tricks.

Comment: You probably shouldn't use a `Stream` for such a simple task, especially with 10 million cars. Why not maintain a `Set` of car types you already have, then call `Set#contains` whenever you need to check if a type is present? You can dodge a lot of iterations by manually iterating through all the cars, since you don't need the full filtering of `Stream#filter`, which iterates over *all* elements: if `reportElements` has 10 million entries, yet `Honda` and `Civic` took up the first 2 indexes, you're wasting a lot of time filtering through the rest.

Comment: I used cars but it could just easily have been people. I just thought cars was easier to see performance wise. Either way you still have to loop through the whole list of millions of cars to create the set in the first place, so you're still running an O(n) if you create a pre-set. Also it may not be possible to maintain a cache set of cars if the list is dependent on a query. This is using people instead of cars may be a better example ;)

Comment: It doesn't matter if it were cars, people or ducks. `filter` iterates through the *entire* collection, so either way there's that `O(n)` operation being performed. Big O is for *worst-case scenarios* - that doesn't mean you can't improve the time for better situations (such as the one I described above, with `Honda` and `Civic` being at the front of the collection).

Comment: @VinceEmigh Just to add. An example could be IP x and IP y BOTH make login attempts on server z between such and such a date. In this case my list of IP attempts is going to different each query. There could be a number of reasons why I'm only interested if I see both IP's. Another example could be finding credit card fraud over a period of time. Neither of these examples apply to my specific case other than to say that the list cannot be cached into a set.

Comment: @VinceEmigh True, but the answer I selected actually does short circuit the search so it stops as soon as the first two items I want are found. And it has minimal memory requirements. So it is possible without maintaining an O(n) set ;)

Comment: The short circuiting *doesn't* make it stop prematurely (as you'd want). The short circuiting doesn't affect how many items are iterated over, it only affects how many items make it over to the next operation. Instead of "*Is the current item a Focus*", it's "*Is the current item a Focus OR a Civic*"? The number of current items scanned doesn't change. And it's not *minimal* memory: `Stream` wasn't built to be cheap, it was built to be powerful.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Actually, the short circuiting DOES make it stop prematurely.  Look at the example I added with an INFINITE stream of models.  The stream pipeline stops after just 7 elements have been generated.  Note the  `peek()` stages that appear before the `limit()` only get executed at most 7 times each.  Try the example without the `limit()` for comparison.  You'll see the limit doesn't just affect how many items make it over to the next stage, but surprisingly, how many make it to previous stages.  It is a `break` statement for the stream's loop.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could filter the stream on `"Civic" or "Focus"`, and then run a collector on `getModel()` returning a `Set<String>`.  Then you could test if your set contains both keys.

```
Set<String> models = reportElements.stream()
       .map(Car::getModel)
       .filter(model -> model.equals("Focus") || model.equals("Civic"))
       .collect(Collectors.toSet());
return models.contains("Focus") && models.contains("Civic");
```

However, this would process the entire stream; it wouldn't "fast succeed" when both have been found.

---

The following is a "fast succeed" short-circuiting method.  (Updated to include comments and clarifications from comments, below)

```
return reportElements.stream()
           .map(Car::getModel)
           .filter(model -> model.equals("Focus") || model.equals("Civic"))
           .distinct()
           .limit(2)
           .count() == 2;
```

Breaking the stream operations down one at a time, we have:

```
           .map(Car::getModel)
```

This operation transforms the stream of cars into a stream of car models.
We do this for efficiency.
Instead of calling `car.getModel()` multiple times in various places in the remainder of the pipeline (twice in the `filter(...)` to test against each of the desired models, and again for the `distinct()` operation), we apply this mapping operation once.
Note that this does not create the "temporary map" mentioned in the comments;
it merely translates the car into the car's model for the next stage of the pipeline.

```
           .filter(model -> model.equals("Focus") || model.equals("Civic"))
```

This filters the stream of car models, allowing only the "Focus" and "Civic" car models to pass.

```
           .distinct()
```

This pipeline operation is a [stateful intermediate operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps).
It remembers each car model that it sees in a temporary `Set`.
(This is likely the "temporary map" mentioned in the comments.)
Only if the model does not exist in the temporary set,
will it be (a) added to the set, and (b) passed on to the next stage of the pipeline.

At this point in the pipeline, there can only be at most two elements in the stream: "Focus" or "Civic" or neither or both.
We know this because we know the `filter(...)` will only ever pass those two models, and we know that `distinct()` will remove any duplicates.

However, this stream pipeline itself does not know that.
It would continue to pass car objects to the `map` stage to be converted into model strings, pass these models to the `filter` stage, and send on any matching items to the `distinct` stage.
It cannot tell that this is futile, because it doesn't understand that nothing else can pass through the algorithm; it simple executes the instructions.

But ***we*** do understand.
At most two distinct models can pass through the `distinct()` stage.
So, we follow this with:

```
           .limit(2)
```

This is a  [short-circuiting stateful intermediate operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps).
It maintains a count of the number of items which pass through, and
after the indicated amount, it terminates the stream, causing all subsequent items to be discarded without even starting down the pipeline.

At this point in the pipeline, there can only be at most two elements in the stream: "Focus" or "Civic" or neither or both.
But if both, then the stream has been truncated and is at the end.

```
           .count() == 2;
```

Count up the number of items that made it through the pipeline,
and test against the desired number.

If we found both models, the stream will immediate terminate, `count()` will return 2, and `true` will be returned.
If both models are not present, of course, the stream is processed until the bitter end, `count()` will return a value less that two, and `false` will result.

---

Example, using an infinite stream of models.
Every third model is a "Civic", every 7th model is a "Focus", the remainder are all "Model #":

```
boolean matched = IntStream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1)
    .mapToObj(i -> i % 3 == 0 ? "Civic" : i % 7 == 0 ? "Focus" : "Model "+i)
    .peek(System.out::println)
    .filter(model -> model.equals("Civic") || model.equals("Focus"))
    .peek(model -> System.out.println("  After filter:   " + model))
    .distinct()
    .peek(model -> System.out.println("  After distinct: " + model))
    .limit(2)
    .peek(model -> System.out.println("  After limit:    " + model))
    .count() == 2;
System.out.println("Matched = "+matched);
```

Output:

```
Model 1
Model 2
Civic
  After filter:   Civic
  After distinct: Civic
  After limit:    Civic
Model 4
Model 5
Civic
  After filter:   Civic
Focus
  After filter:   Focus
  After distinct: Focus
  After limit:    Focus
Matched = true
```

Notice that 3 models got through the `filter()`, but only 2 made it past `distinct()` and `limit()`.
More importantly, notice that `true` was returned long before the end of the infinite stream of models was reached.

---

Generalizing the solution, since the OP wants something that could work with people, or credit cards, or IP addresses, etc., and the search criteria is probably not a fixed set of two items:

```
Set<String> models = Set.of("Focus", "Civic");

return reportElements.stream()
           .map( Car::getModel )
           .filter( models::contains )
           .distinct()
           .limit( models.size() )
           .count() == models.size();
```

Here, given an arbitrary `models` set, existence of any particular set of car models may be obtained, not limited to just 2.

Comment: That's a minimum N algorithm plus whatever the result size of Civics and Focuses. I suspect that running two streams would be more efficient in most cases...

Comment: I really like the use of limit(). Great idea!! Unfortunately there is still a problem with the solution where the temporary map of models could consume a lot of memory. I used cars but imagine now it's people and I have a millions of people. In that case the temporary map could hold millions of strings in memory to find two people if the two people were at the end of the list :(

Comment: No, the filtering is done before `distinct`, so the temporary map would only grow to the size of the set you are looking for.

Comment: After `distinct` there will be no more than 2 elements, so `limit` here is redundant

Comment: @ByeBye No, after `distinct()`, there is a possibly infinite stream containing only distinct items passing the filter.  With the `limit(2)`, when the stream has emitted the second item, processing of the stream stops.  This gives the short-circuiting fast succeed.

Comment: Yup, I think that may be the answer after all. Small but subtle detail.

Comment: Why did you create a temporary Set, not used '.filter(model -> model.equals("Focus") || model.equals("Civic"))'?

Comment: @123-xyz Just trying to be fancy / lazy.  `.filter(model -> model.equals("Focus") || model.equals("Civic"))` would work, and is probably faster.  But with a larger number of items to search for (say 10 particular models), the temporary set and `contains` should be faster.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
reportElements.stream()
    .filter(car -> "Civic".equals(car.getModel()) || "Focus".equals(car.getModel()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            c -> c.getModel(),
            c -> c,
            (c1, c2) -> c1
    )).size() == 2;
```

or even with `Set`

```
reportElements.stream()
    .filter(car -> "Civic".equals(car.getModel()) || "Focus".equals(car.getModel()))
    .map(car -> car.getModel())
    .collect(Collectors.toSet())
    .size() == 2;
```

and with `distinct`

```
reportElements.stream()
    .filter(car -> "Civic".equals(car.getModel()) || "Focus".equals(car.getModel()))
    .map(car -> car.getModel())
    .distinct()
    .count() == 2L;
```

Comment: I don't think that's valid, as it returns truthy for a list with two Civics or two Focuses (and none of the other type) - could maybe add `.distinct()`

Comment: That's exactly why you can't rely on size :(

Comment: @StephaneGrenier I'm fairly sure you're good to go with `.distinct`, though, as multiple Civics/Focuses will reduce to 1.

Comment: @TylerSebastian I think you're right. The key is that you absolutely need distinct otherwise it won't work

Comment: @StephaneGrenier you can use my answet with set, I think it is valid now

Comment: @ByeBye I don't think you can use set because that's based on the hashcode which may or may not be equal for different types of Civics. In other words car1 which is a Civic may have a different hashcode than car2 which is also a civic. I think the valid option is distinctByKey where you can set the key to be the model. If you want to adjust the answer to that I'll accept it.

Comment: @StephaneGrenier I mapped it to `String` first

Comment: And acctually `Set` works on `equals` not `hashcodes`

Comment: Actually after thinking about it even though this will work it's probably going to have much worse performance then two streams. Reason being is that you're guaranteed an N algorithm with those solutions. With two streams it ends as soon as one is found. So if I had a list of 1 million cars with two streams the search could be done with two comparisons. With your solution I would be guaranteed O(n) which is 1 million comparisons :(

Comment: Yup, you are right, it can be true (if JIT will not optimize it because of `== 2` - dunno). But your question was to proceed it in one stream, not about optimization :)

Comment: Your right it does answer the question. But at the same time you don't want to add a significant performance penalty either. Going from O(1) to O(n) is a big penalty. In that case I would say it is not possible :(

Comment: It is still O(n) in average

Comment: Maybe you can do it with just `for loop`? It will be fast ended and will be faster anyway then streams

Comment: Yes you're right an old school for loop is the most efficient. The more I think about the less I think there is a viable option with streams for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it "doesn't feel right" is because you are forcing the stream API to do something it doesn't want to do. You would almost surely be better off with a traditional loop:

```
boolean hasFocus = false, hasCivic = false;
for (Car c : reportElements) {
    if ("Focus".equals(c.getModel())) hasFocus = true;
    if ("Civic".equals(c.getModel())) hasCivic = true;
    if (hasFocus & hasCivic) return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: How are these operations something the stream api doesn't want to do? It isn't modifying any data and is a compliant lambda expression.